# How to avoid a hyphen from splitting a regex?

Tags: java, android, regex

I'm writing a simple android app for saving your favorite games in a list.

In the first screen a user has to enter his `gamertag` (as a `String`). The gamertag should only contain `letters` from `a-z (uppercase and lowercase)`, `numbers (0-9)` and `underscores/hpyhens (_ and -)`.

I can get it to work with an `underscore` in every position or a `hyphen` at the beginning. But if the `String` contains a `hyphen` in the middle it gets `"split`" into two pieces and if the `hyphen` is at the end, it stands alone.

I came up with this `regex`:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]\w+
```

in java it looks a little different because the \ needs to be escaped:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_\\-]\\w+
```

`Gamertags` that should validate:

```
- GamerTag
- Gamer_Tag
- _GamerTag
- GamerTag_
- -GamerTag
- Gamer-Tag
- GamerTag-
```

`Gamertags` that shouldn't validate:

```
- !GamerTag
- Gamer%Tag
- Gamer Tag
```

`Gamertags` that should validate, but my `regex` fails:

```
- Gamer-Tag
- GamerTag-
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your pattern `[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]\w+` matches 1 character out of the character class followed by 1+ times a word character `\w` which does not match a `-`.

You could repeat the character class 1+ times where the hyphen is present  and if the hyphen is at the end of the character class you don't have to eacape it.

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+
```

The `Gamer-Tag` does not get split but has 2 matches. The character class matches `G` and the `\w+` matches `amer`. Then in the next match the character class matches `-` and `\w+` matches `Tag`.

If those are the only values allowed, you could use anchors `^` to assert the start and `$` to assert the end of the string.

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gu4g48/1)